# Samba 3.6 on AIX 7.1 - Windows 10 Access to AIX file shares using Active Directory authentication

Tags: windows-server-2012, samba, windows-10, aix

I am running AIX 7.1 and currently we have samba 3.6.25 installed on the server. As it stands some AIX folders are shared that can be accessed by certain Windows users. Kerberos is not installed on the server currently.

The problem is that since Windows 10 the guest feature no longer works so users have to manually type in their Windows login/pwd before they can access the shared drives. They get a pop up box asking them to login.  Previously users were able to connect to the AIX file shares with no requirement to enter username/passwords.

My requirement:
I need to reconfigure samba so that a small group of Windows users in a specific group on Active Directory can access these shared folders on AIX without the requirement to enter their login and password. Samba should recognise the user they are currently logged in as on Active Directory and allow them access to the folder if they are a member of the right access group.

My current smb.conf is as follows:

workgroup = domain
wins support = yes
security = user
log file = /var/log/samba.log
protocol = SMB2
min protocol = SMB2                 ## This had to be added so that Windows 10 machines can access the share as SMB1 is not supported

[File Share]
path = /filetoshare/here
force user = root
read only = no
public = yes
guest ok = no

I understand from my initial research that I need to change the security from user to ADS by setting security = ADS. This would then allow me to use Active Directory to authenticate the users. Unfortunately after checking the nmbd logs it seems that this setting is not recognised by this version of Samba 3.6...

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'ADS' for parameter 'security'
Ignoring unknown parameter "realm"
```

It may be that Samba 3.6 does not support ADS. In this case do I have any other options with Samba 3.6 that would allow me to authenticate with the Windows Domain running on Windows Server 2012? I see there is also a server setting of domain - server = domain. I understand the AIX machine name would need to be added to the active directory server under machines I presume?

When looking at adding Samba to domains there was reference to a command "net ads -u Username" I get another error.

```
ADS support not compiled in
```

So I presume this means I can't use the domain option either which would suggest I need a newer version of Samba.

I have checked many AIX forums but have not been able to find a pre-compiled version of samba 4 for AIX 7.1. This would be the safest way to upgrade. 
Unfortunately this AIX machine does not have GCC, WGET, YUM installed so it would be difficult to compile from source. If this was Ubuntu I'd just run an apt-get install samba but AIX is a different beast. Also can anyone confirm if I need to also install Kerberos for this to work?

I'd be interested to hear if anyone has this working. Any suggestions to help with this project would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AIX Toolbox repository to download the latest available SMB for AIX.

Related links:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=97038d17-97b7-4304-a5a5-4d5b81266c5e

Use the yum.sh (mentioned in the link) to install yum on your AIX if it is not already installed and use it to easily update all your packages from the official repository.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this a few months ago with

1) Upgraded RPM to latest version as I found current version of RPM did not allow me to install RPM packages I required

Navigate to ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/INSTALLP/ppc/ and download rpm.rte

Ran smit and installed using software installation menu

2) Downloaded YUM package

Download YUM bundle from the following location
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/yum_bundle.tar

Ran smit and installed using software installation menu

Once yum was installed I then managed to install Samba and other software required as follows

yum install samba.ppc krb5-server.ppc krb5-workstation samba-winbind-krb5-locator.ppc samba-winbind-devel.ppc libsmbclient-devel.ppc openldap-devel.ppc samba-winbind.ppc samba-winbind-clients.ppc samba-libs.ppc

Now move WINBIND library to correct folder

mv /opt/freeware/lib/WINBIND.so /usr/lib/security
cd /usr/lib/security
mv WINDBIND.so WINBIND
chown root:security WINBIND

**Kerberos**

1) kinit  using my current Windows user name that I log on to the domain with. Initially I had some problems with time synchronisation (scew time was out). To resolve this I configured ntp daemon pointing it to the domain server and I forced a time synchronisation. After this the command worked and I generated a kerberos key.

2) net ads join -U  using my current Windows user name that I log on to the domain with.

Both these commands worked so I joined the Windows domain.

At this stage I ran some test commands:

wbinfo --ping-dc - This came back positive as SUCCESS

wbinfo -g - This brings back a list of all domain groups on the domain controller
wbinfo -u - This brings back a list in unix of all the windows user names on the domain controller

**Config Files**

SAMBA.CONF
Code:
server string = "IBM AIX Server"
log file = /var/log/samba.log
passdb backend = tdbsam
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range   = 1000-9999
idmap config UTILITY :backend = ad
idmap config UTILITY:schema_mode = rfc2307
idmap config UTILITY:range = 10000-10099

log level = 3
netbios name = AIXBOX
workgroup = ROBOT
usershare allow guests = yes
domain master = no
local master = no
password server = *
realm = ROBOT.LOCAL
security = ADS
encrypt passwords = yes
template shell = /usr/bin/bash
interfaces = en0
winbind use default domain = yes
client use spnego = no

[testshare]
path = /home/share
read only = No
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
public = yes
browseable = yes
valid users = @"domain computers"

[test]
path = /buuk
browseable = yes
valid users = my_windows_user_name

METHODS.CONF
Code:
WINBIND:
        program = /usr/lib/security/WINBIND

NIS:
        program = /usr/lib/security/NIS
        program_64 = /usr/lib/security/NIS_64

DCE:
        program = /usr/lib/security/DCE   (DOES NOT EXIST ON MY AIX SYSTEM)

KRB5A:
        program = /usr/lib/security/KRB5A
        options = authonly

KRB5files:
        options = db=BUILTIN,auth=KRB5A

KRB5.CONF

Code:
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = ROBOT.LOCAL
 default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 ROBOT.LOCAL = {
  kdc = KDC.ROBOT.LOCAL
  default_domain = ROBOT.LOCAL
 }

Hope this helps.